# C# Media Player PlayStateChange not firing

Tags: c#, wmplib

Trying to get a WMPLib to go to the next track when the current one ends. My code is below, but it never fires. I've tried with WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped as well as WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded and it never fires. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? The media player is afile.

Thanks in advance.

```
private void mediaPlayer_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Playstate Has Fired");
        if (mediaPlayer.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)  // check if file has ended.
        {
            try
            {
                listFiles.SelectedIndex++;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (chkLoop.Checked)
                {
                    listFiles.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    afile.controls.stop();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the event is not fired or the condition is not met ? Do you get the messagebox ?

Comment: @AnuViswan I do not get the messagebox at all.

Comment: Could you check if the event is actually subscribed ? mediaPlayer.PlayStateChange += mediaPlayer_PlayStateChange;

Comment: I'm a little lost on that one. Where would I put that code?

Comment: How did you create the mediaPlayer_PlayStateChange method ? Did you create it by using PropertyWindow of MediaPlayer or manually added delegate ? or you copy pasted this code ?

Comment: You can add that to your InitializeComponent method or your constructor. Ensure it is part of code that is not executed more than one, since you do not want multiple binding

Comment: Thank you! I used a timer to check the PlayState, worked great.

Comment: that would be bad idea to do. It is better if you subscribe to the PlayStateChange event

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I got this figured out by using a timer_tick event, and adding this to it:

```
if (afile.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
        {
            listFiles.SelectedIndex++;
        }
```

Works great. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, what is afile? and mediaPlayer ? are you have two media player controls ?

Comment: afile is my name for the media player control. Just one media player control.

Comment: so what is mediaPlayer in "mediaPlayer.playState" ?